# Calling a JUnit ANT task from a Java Class

Tags: java, ant, junit

I am attempting to run a JUnit ant task from a java class using this java code:

```
File buildFile = new File("build\\build-junit.xml");
System.out.println("Running the tests");
Project project = new Project();
project.setUserProperty("ant.file", buildFile.getAbsolutePath());
project.init();
ProjectHelper helper = ProjectHelper.getProjectHelper();
project.addReference("ant.projectHelper", helper);
helper.parse(project, buildFile);
project.executeTarget(project.getDefaultTarget());
```

Here is the Ant script source that it attempts to run:
            http://jpst.it/j6K3 (Sorry for the inconvenience, pasting in the source code was giving me issues)

Finally here is the Exception thrown:

> Exception in thread "main" C:\hudson\workspace\FestTesting\exchange\build\build-junit.xml:31: Could not create task or type of type: junit.

Do any of you know what I could do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

this error usually occurs when the required `.jar`s are missing from the `classpath`. now, in your `Ant script` you've passed a reference to `"classpath"` via:

```
<junit ...
<classpath refid="classpath" />
...
</junit>
```

but the `<pathelement>`s of **"classpath"** can be incomplete. make sure you've included `JUnit.jar` and `ant-junit.jar`. something like this:

```
<path id="classpath">
    ...
    <pathelement location="...\junit.jar" />
    ...
</path>
```

although, `ant-junit.jar` is likely to be present at `$ANT_HOME\lib`, do verify it. **if it is missing**, then make the following changes:

```
<path id="classpath">
    ...
    <pathelement location="...\junit.jar" />
    <pathelement location="...\ant-junit.jar" />
    ...
</path>
```

Go through [**THIS**](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html)